# How can I receive an array, comparing two other arrays using aggregation framework?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

How am i supposed to build my pipeline in MongoDB if, lets say i got this collection:

```
[
 {_id: 1, field: "somevalue", array: ["123", "abc", "456", "def"]},
 {_id: 2, field: "somevalue", array: ["zxc", "abc", "vbn", "jkl"]},
 {_id: 3, field: "somevalue", array: ["fgh", "asd", "456", "def"]}
]
```

And I want receive in a new field, new array of values that matches values from my current array?

Lets say I got this array which i want to campare with:

```
[ "abc", "456"]
```

So I'm expecting to receive this:

```
[
 {_id: 1, field: "somevalue", array: ["123", "abc", "456", "def"], myNewArray: ["abc", "456"]},
 {_id: 2, field: "somevalue", array: ["zxc", "abc", "vbn", "jkl"], myNewArray: ["abc"]},
 {_id: 3, field: "somevalue", array: ["fgh", "asd", "456", "def"], myNewArray: ["456"]}
]
```

How exactly can I build my pipeline to receive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [$setIntersection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) operator to keep only elements present in your array parameter.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "newArray": {
        $setIntersection: [
          [
            "abc",
            "456"
          ],
          "$array"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[You can test it here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qWTFFqT9F-K)